# Is there a function to track changes on a status field, and trigger actions for specific changes

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

Is there a way to track the changes on a status field and specify different actions based on different statuses? The key here is the ability to differentiate two scenarios:

1. status being changed from `In-Progress` to `Completed`
2. status being changed from `Publish CADs` to `Completed`.

I want to trigger different actions based on different scenarios and look for a Deluge or Python script.

Comment: what zoho apps are you using?

Comment: We are Zoho One users so we use multiple Zoho Applications, the above concern is related to ZOHO CRM.